# Elastic Beanstalk Deploying Issue - Production Database Is Not Configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rails-api

I am having issues deploying my Rails API to Elastic Beanstalk. I cannot seem to get rid of the following error: `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]`

Please help me figure this out. I am attaching details below.

#### /config/database.yml

`default: &defaults
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      min_messages: warning
      pool: 5
      timeout: 10000
      username: postgres
      host:     localhost
    production:
      <<: *defaults
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
      username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
      password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
      host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
      port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
      pool: 5`

#### /config/environments/production.rb

`config.assets.compile = false`

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

#### EB Logs

`` [Instance: i-13bf48db] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks' /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define' Tasks: TOP => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace). Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI. ``

and

`` +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.1.5
    +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
    +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
    ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
    + cd /var/app/ondeck
    + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
    + '[' false == true ']'
    + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]
    /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection' ``

Comment: is database.yml in your .gitignore? Are you using the CLI to deploy?

Comment: Yes, the database.yml was in my .gitignore. After removing it, everything worked. Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 0):

If it is not in .gitignore, please give the credentials in your database.yml  for the environment that you want to do.